# Is there a function to predict value of x (x-ose) based on the y value when using sklearn.LinearRegression()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, prediction

Is there a function to predict the value of x (x-axe) based on the y value?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
lin = LinearRegression()
 ...
lin.fit(x, y)
lin.predict(110.0)
```

With this code, I can approximately say what is the value of y for input x.
Is there a vice versa way, where I can say what is the value of x based on the y ?

With the LinearRegresion (or Exponential) it is quite easy, I can get coefficients of the regression and find the inverse function. Then I can easily get the value of x based on y, but I have problems when I am using polynomial regression, finding an inverse function is a little bit more complex than for linear function?

Is there an easy way, to predict how much x - values have left before reaching some y-value?

The simplest example I can imagine now is if we have a graph of distance and fuel consumption (see Img1). I know that with  *lin.predic(x1)* I can get the value of *limit*, but can I do something like *function(limit)* to get x1?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKd8.png)

Tnx.

Comment: you need to flip x and y, refit `lin.fit(y,x)` and then `lin.predict(y)`

Comment: Hi Sergey, that should work, good idea, tnx. 
Then I would need two linear regression  one normal and one inverse.

Comment: You may though get coefficients as `lin.coef_` and express `x = f(y)`

Comment: yes, it is easy for linear regression or exponential, but if I want polynomial (2nd, 3rd ... order) it would be a little bit tricky. y = ax²+bx+c.